# pressing a button in an ie page using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I've been trying to manipulate an internal website using vba but I have run into a problem. Currently, my script below opens the webpage and enters the values of cell a1 in sheet1 into the text box on the webpage. My problem is when I try to click on the search button I get the following message "run time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method". I have tried a few different ways but none work. Also I have added the button properties when I inspect element. Thanks!

```
<input name="Action" onclick="this.disabled=true; this.form.submit();" type="submit" value="Search">


Sub autoIE()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate "webpage.com"

IE.Visible = True

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

IE.document.all("lookupNumberId").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a1")

IE.document.all("Action").Click 'error 438

IE.document.getElementByName("Action").Click 'error 438

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a single element with that name on the page?

Comment: Yes, that's the only element with that name.

Comment: Try `IE.document.getElementsByName("Action")(0).Click`

Comment: I *think* `IE.document.getElementByName("Action")` returns an array (or array-like collection), and then you'd need to figure out which item is the right one. If its the only one, you might insert `(0)` between `("Action")` and `.Click`

Comment: I tried BruceWayne's suggesting and this time I did not get an error message but nothing happen. But I changed `(0)` to `(1)` and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think the code is looking for actual keypress event ! Tell me are you searching in WBK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an FYI BruceWayne's suggesting worked for me but I just had to change `(0)` to `(1)`.

`IE.document.getElementsByName("Action")(1).Click`